# Wordpress thumbnail image is only resized by html

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a wordpress/woocommerce website designed by Elementor and I need to view some of my products in a carousel.

My thumbnails are generated currectly and my theme is supporting thumb-sizes by default.
When I check my website and its showing "full" size image with html width & height attributes resized to my thumb sizes.

```
<img alt="" data-src="https://mywebsite.tld/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/1-1.jpg" class="attachment-thumb size-thumb wp-post-image wp-post-image lazyloaded" src="https://mywebsite.tld/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/1-1.jpg" width="192" height="192">
```

As far as I know the src should be something like this:

```
<img src="https://mywebsite.tld/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/1-1-192x192.jpg">
```

I dont know how to achieve this but I have done so many searches and lots of debugging and still nothing.

1. Removed All Plugins
2. Add New Sizes by using *Array (192, 192)* method and new size names.
3. Changed to another themes supporting Elementor.
4. Regenerating Thumbnails
5. Re-upload some Images

and more ...

the interesting part is that when I change the thumb size inside **functions.php**, the html width and height attributes change to my preferred size! but the image is still loaded from the main source!

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

I was searching and found a similar situation and their answer was that the aspect ratio of images is not changing so the final output doesn't do anything. so I have changed my sizes a bit to change the aspect ratio and using 192x190px and still no luck...

this is a function for loading images in my theme's functions.php:

```
function p_img() { 
   if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {
             the_post_thumbnail('woocommerce_thumbnail'); 
    } else { 
    echo '<img src="'.esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ).'/images/tumb.png" alt="'.the_title_attribute('echo=0').'" class="post-tumb"/>';
    }
}
```

This is the part of my carousel widget that shows up the images using owl carousel:

```
<div class="item">
                <div class="woocommerce shadow-box <?php echo $di_data['prod_hover']; ?> mini-product<?php echo $stock_class; ?><?php echo $coming_class; ?>">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" class="product-link">
                        <?php p_img() ?>
                        <?php if($in_stock && $product->is_on_sale()) { ?>
                        <?php echo dina_dis_price(get_the_ID()); ?>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <span class="product-title">
                            <?php the_title(); ?>
                        </span>
                        <span class="product-price">
                        <?php if($in_stock) { ?>
                            <span class="price-con">
                            <?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?>
                            </span>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                            <span class="price-con">
                            <?php _e( 'Out of stock', 'dina-kala' ); ?>
                            </span>
                        <?php } ?>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                    <?php dina_add_to_cart($product); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
```

This is the inspect of Customize Section in my theme:

```
<img alt="" data-src="https://mywebsite.tld/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/YB-Product-905-2-192x190.jpg" class="attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail wp-post-image wp-post-image ls-is-cached lazyloaded" src="https://mywebsite.tld/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/YB-Product-905-2-192x190.jpg" width="192" height="190">
```

this is my live website:

```
<img alt="" data-src="https://mywebsite.tld/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/T-Shit-C-shirt-2.jpg" class="attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail wp-post-image wp-post-image lazyloaded" src="https://mywebsite.tld/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/T-Shit-C-shirt-2.jpg" width="192" height="190">
```

Comment: I think this is important for us to know how you insert the images. If you use some Elementor element and select the correct image size, but it outputs the full size (even though the featured image size is existing on your webserver), you should contact the plugin authors. There might be a problem with the element you are using to insert the images. Have you tried outputting images of this size somewhere else?

Comment: Update:
When I Open the customize section of wordpress theme and use inspector i can see that images are loaded with -192x192.jpg at the end of src file name! but in live site it doesn't do that! I also found another similar question here that it said the  aspect ratio of sizes is not changing then it does nothing. so I tested with diffrent ratio and still nothing!!

Comment: hey rank, I have uploaded images via "add featured image" option in "add new product", also generated/regenrated by different plugins.

Comment: Also I have checked the plugin related to Elementor and its working fine! on their demo is working fine and the code is working on my website. as I said it doesnt have -192x192 at the end of src. please check my Updated comment

Comment: Without any code it will be hard to help you. I think contacting the plugin author would be best, as it seems to be a problem with that. In your customizer the correct files are loaded but in the frontend they are not.... Are you using any cache plugins or have custom edits in your functions.php or in (child-)theme files?

Comment: I'll post some of the code here in a few seconds.

Comment: Rank, I have updated my question with some more information...

Comment: I can view my thumbnails directly, I disabled any caching plugin, my functions.php and my theme are installed by theme's developer